# How to call an external java function with Xalan processor

Tags: java, xslt, namespaces, xalan

I'm having trouble to call an external java function in my XSL code with Xalan processor.

The error I get is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: For extension function, could not find method org.apache.xml.utils.NodeVector.incrementPropertyId([ExpressionContext,] ).
```

I have a java class named Util.java in the folder where I execute my compile command.

In my xsl file, I've declared my namespace as follow :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                          xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java" exclude-result-prefixes="java"
                          xmlns:util="xalan://Util">
```

And I call my function using :

```
<xsl:copy-of select="util:incrementPropertyId(blablabal)"/>
```

So I suppose my problem comes from my namespace, but what is wrong with it ?

Also, It's a xsl 1.0 stylesheet.

Thanks for your help

Edit :

In my Util.java file, I have no package declared since I'm at the root... should I add a package Util; definition to my class ?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue with latest Xalan (2.7)... did it get resolved somehow ?

Comment: @lazertyuiopl Nope, found out it was impossible with Xalan.

Answer (score 1):

define your name space util in the extension-element-prefix, and assign to this namespace the package and the name of your class:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                      xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java" exclude-result-prefixes="java"
                      extension-element-prefix="util"
                      xmlns:util="your.package.YourClass">
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your problem is that you haven't mentioned namespace when calling a method
Try:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="util:incrementPropertyId()"/>
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I have mentioned a namespace just forgot to type when asking my question.